# How you use fopen/fwrite on a js file?

Tags: php, fopen

I am trying to do this

```
$fp = fopen('all.js', 'w');
fwrite($fp, 'sddddddddddddddddddddd');
echo "<script src=\"/inc/all.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>";
```

but the file is always empty...can you use fwrite on a js file and write to it...i checked permissions and all is good there...any ideas?

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled? Does `$fp` contain a file pointer?

Comment: How does one check if its a valid filepointer

Comment: look in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Comment: @Tamer: `fopen` returns a pointer if it worked, or `FALSE` if it didn't.

Comment: @tamer: fopen return boolean FALSE if the open fails. so... `$fp = fopen(...); if ($fp === FALSE) { die("Unable to open file"); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fwrite couldn't care less if you're writing text, js, php, or raw binary garbage. It just outputs what you tell it to.

The problem is that you're writing out to `all.js`, but are refering to `/inc/all.js` in your script tag. Unless your script's current-working-directory is set to whatever directory the URL `/inc` maps to on your server, you're writing in one place, but reading from another.

Comment: yes thats true but i even look in the file and nothing is there..the file is empty

Comment: figured it out the path was starting at the top of the document root

Comment: Are you looking in the right spot? For instance, if the script's running as `/home/wwwroot/script.php`, then your fopen is creating `/home/wwwroot/all.js`. But your HTML output is going to be looking for `/home/wwwroot/inc/all.js` instead.